# Angular and HTML datepicker

Tags: html, angular, date

I want to display a date in HTML `input type="date"` from a variable in my ts file.

ScreenDate is a variable in my ts file.

```
<input type="date" [(ngModel)]="ScreenDate">
```

This did not work.

```
<input type="date" value="{{ScreenDate}}">
```

This also did not work and since I need the value the user chose I need to bind the variable back to my ts file.

Any Help will be much appreciated

Comment: It would help to see a little of the TypeScript code. The value or `ScreenDate` matters - the input field only works with certain date formats.

And I know you wrote "Missed "<" on purpose", but why?

Comment: We cannot help you if you don't show us the ts code.

Comment: Hi, forgive me for not knowing how this editor works a pointer to that will be helptull. this is my ts code "ScreenDate: Date ;" and "this.ScreenDate = new Date("2018-01-02");"

Answer (score 0):

You have to add date pipe

```
 <input type="date" value="{{ScreenDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}">
```

OR

```
<input type="date" [ngModel] ="ScreenDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'" (ngModelChange)="ScreenDate = $event">
```

Ts Code

```
 ScreenDate = new Date();
```